# PHP: Return response immediately, but run multiple lengthy shell_exec functions in the background

Tags: php, asynchronous, ffmpeg, shell-exec

I am creating a simple web service that accepts a video upload, runs multiple different encodes on the video (mp4, webm, ogv), and then uploads the newly created files to our video host.

Let's say I have multiple commands..

```
shell_exec('ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 24 -s 1280x720 -c:a libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he -ar 22050 -b:a 64k -movflags +faststart output-1280x720.mp4');

shell_exec('ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 24 -s 1920x1080 -c:a libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he -ar 22050 -b:a 64k -movflags +faststart output-1920x1080.mp4');

shell_exec('ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f ogg -c:v libtheora -q:v 5 -s 1280x720 -c:a libvorbis -ar 22050 -b:a 64k -movflags +faststart output-1280x720.ogv');

shell_exec('ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f ogg -c:v libtheora -q:v 5 -s 1920x1080 -c:a libvorbis -ar 22050 -b:a 64k -movflags +faststart output-1920x1080.ogv');
```

In summary, I want to...

1. Print an immediate response: {success: true}
2. Kick off multiple ffmpeg jobs synchronously.
3. After each job is complete, send a POST to another server (one POST for each shell_exec).

It would also be nice to only send the POST if the job was successful, but I could easily work around that by just checking to see if the output file exists on the server.

I know that I can force shell_exec to run in the background by simply appending `>/dev/null 2>/dev/null &` to each command -- which would allow me to print a response immediately -- but I think by doing this, this would cause all of the jobs to run in parallel, and also, since this is diverting the output, I do not get any true callbacks when jobs are complete.

Any ideas??

Comment: Just an idea... If you create an new PHP script for each command and then call this script instead to run the command directly? On the end of the script you can send to the server a notification that the operation is complete.

Comment: You could always just put that code in another PHP file and call it with CURL as a external file e.g. http://yourwebsite.com/api/apifilecall.php while setting a really low timeout in CURL. P.S. Your second line has three single quotes which breaks the code :).

Comment: Both good suggestions. I'm going to give this a go. I'll report back if it works.

Comment: This worked, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: You don't need `-movflags +faststart` for the ogv outputs; it's only for the mov/mp4 muxer. Instead of old, graybeard theora, consider using libvpx for VP8/VP9 video and opus audio in webm.

Comment: What about WebM -- does that leverage `-movflags +faststart`?

Comment: These are my current commands:

`'ffmpeg -i {{input}} -f mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 24 -s 1280x720 -c:a libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he -ar 22050 -b:a 64k -movflags +faststart {{output}}'`

 || 

`'ffmpeg -i {{input}} -f webm -c:v libvpx -g 120 -lag-in-frames 16 -deadline good -cpu-used 0 -vprofile 0 -slices 4 -qmax 50 -qmin 0 -crf 10 -b:v 1.25M -s 1280x720 -c:a libvorbis -ar 22050 -b:a 64k -movflags +faststart {{output}}'`

 || 

`'ffmpeg -i {{input}} -f ogg -c:v libtheora -q:v 5 -s 1280x720 -c:a libvorbis -ar 22050 -b:a 64k -movflags +faststart {{output}}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with the idea of requesting the file asynchronously. To keep it clean, I was able to keep it all contained in a single file that "re-calls" itself with a different POST request.

```
$root_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/';
$root_http = 'http' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';

function request_async($url, $params, $type='POST', $timeout=30) {
  foreach ($params as $key => &$val) {
    if (is_array($val)) $val = implode(',', $val);
    $post_params[] = $key.'='.urlencode($val);
  }
  $post_string = implode('&', $post_params);

  $parts = parse_url($url);

  $fp = fsockopen(
    $parts['host'],
    isset($parts['port']) ? $parts['port'] : 80,
    $errno,
    $errstr,
    $timeout
  );

  if ('GET' == $type) $parts['path'] .= '?'.$post_string;

  $out = "$type ".$parts['path']." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
  $out.= "Host: ".$parts['host']."\r\n";
  $out.= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
  $out.= "Content-Length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n";
  $out.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

  if ('POST' == $type && isset($post_string)) $out .= $post_string;

  fwrite($fp, $out);
  fclose($fp);
}

function get_http_path($path, $relative = FALSE){
  global $root_http, $root_path;
  return str_replace($root_path, $relative ? '/' : $root_http, $path);
}

$url = $_POST['url'];
$media = $_POST['media'];

if (isset($url)) {
  request_async(get_http_path(__FILE__), array(media => $url), 'POST', 1800);
  echo '{"success": true}';
} else
if (isset($media)) {
  $data = file_get_contents($media);
  // KICK OFF JOBS HERE
  echo '{"success": true}';
} else {
  echo '{"success": false}';
}
```